# How to deal with a max in the objective function in an optimisation Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Hello i would like to know how to deal with the following situation and transform it into a standard optimization problem:

$min(a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + max\{x_3, x_4\})$

I know that i can define a new slack variable $(t=max\{x_3, x_4\})$ and put it in the constraints, I also  know how to transform $t\geq max\{x_3, x_4\}$ but with the equality i have no idea. 
Thanks to who is able to clarify this doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\min_t(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+t)$, $t\ge\max\{x_3,x_4\}$, is attained when it is *equality*.

Comment: but why it is not $ t=max\{x_3,x_4\}$ in the constraint?

Comment: @GianniDiGirolamo If you want to solve $\min t$ when $t\ge 1$ then the solution is $t=1$. Here is the same thing, to impose $t\ge\max$ is equivalent to $t=\max$.